# retrofit2 get json object without jsonArray name

Tags: android

I want to take jsonobject using retrofit without class definition, the result is null. How about this ?

I have a get query with JSON response :

```
[{"Kuota":"12"}]
```

This my code get data JSONObject .

```
public void GetKuota(String Key) {
    IBookingService iBookingService = APIClient.getClient().create(IBookingService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = iBookingService.getKuota(Key);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {

                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                     // Log.d(jsonObject.getString("Kuota"));
                     datas =String.valueOf(jsonObject.getInt("Kuota"));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: `if(!response.isSuccessful())` should that ! be there?

Comment: you are parsing JSONArray in JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion:

Create a model class, lets say *Kuota*

```
public class Kuota {
   public int Kuota;
}
```

Then rewrite the Retrofit callback like this.

```
iBookingService.getKuota(Key).enqueue(new Callback<List<Kuota>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Kuota>> call, Response<List<Kuota>> response) {
        if(response.code() == 200 && response.body() != null) {
              try {

                for(Kuota k: response.body()) {
                    Log.d("Kuota Value" , " " + k.kuota);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Kuota>> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

**Replace iBookingService data holder from ResponseBody to List< Kuota >**

if not added, please add the JSON serializer while setting up Retrofit instance.

```
      new Retrofit.Builder()
            .......
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

And also add the dependency

```
  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer my question .. Problem #SOLVED